# Is the normal bundle of an orientable submanifold of an orientable manifold always trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

There is another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495819/is-the-normal-bundle-of-a-hypersurface-in-a-orientable-manifold-trivial) on this site which confirms that for an orientable *hypersurface* of an orientable manifold, the normal bundle is trivial. However, I was wondering if this result generalises to arbitrary orientable submanifolds.

Comment: What is true in that case is that the normal bundle is always _orientable_. For one-dimensional real vector bundles (such as the normal bundle of a hypersurface), orientability is equivalent to triviality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true. For example, take a nontrivial vector bundle $E \to X$, then the zero section $Z \subset E$ has normal bundle isomorphic to $E$.

One can also find example when the ambient space is $\mathbb R^M$, since there are orientable manifolds which [cannot be embedded in the euclidean space with trivial normal bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108481/99914). Together with Whitney's embedding theorem, there are orientable submanifolds in euclidean spaces with nontrivial normal bundle.

Comment: So now I need to know that there exists a nontrivial vector bundle which is orientable and has orientable zero section. It's not obvious to me that such a thing could exist.

Comment: The simplest example would be the tangent bundle $TX=E$ of $X =\mathbb S^2$. The tangent bundle is [always orientable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129514/why-is-the-tangent-bundle-orientable), and $\mathbb S^2$ is also orientable. But it's tangent bundle is nontrivial. @gj255

Comment: I saw the example in this link. But the even dimensional real projective space is non-orientable.

Comment: Do you have some idea in this question? Thanks! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630328/the-relation-between-m-is-orientable-and-the-normal-bundle-of-m-in-mathbb

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/734712/481713